# Should comma in front of colon be omitted?

Tags: punctuation, commas

Should the comma in the sentence below be omitted?

> A comes in two forms, depending on how often they do B:
>
> - X
> - Y
>     .

Comment: The comma is not needed here and is not in front of the colon.  Most bulleted lists end without the period.

Comment: The comma is preferable here to avoid the garden-path alternative reading (two forms which are dependent on ...).